# What technique is it that causes a guitar to whine its notes?

Tags: guitar, technique

I notice that good electric guitarists can make their instrument "whine". What is this technique called and how is it done?

[An example of the technique is found in the piano exit from "Layla".](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BStd6il0H0M&ab_channel=oldschoolen1)

Comment: If you are going to post a link to audio or video at least give the time stamp where you want us to evaluate the "technique"

Comment: This tecnique is eased by using a guitar with a higher action than usual.

Comment: I'd like to extend the comment from @Tim - a little more tension and a little extra height is desired, so something akin to a rhythm guitar setup. Like 10s not 9s. It is common to play normally on your "slide" instrument; a little harder to bend notes, but you _don't_, because you have a slide for that. You don't need to go full dobro.

Answer (score 5):

The "Layla" outro features guitarist Duane Allman using a slide.

Here's how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_guitar) describes slide guitar:

> It involves playing a guitar while holding a hard object (a slide) against the strings, creating the
> opportunity for glissando effects and deep vibratos which reflect
> characteristics of the human singing voice.

Allman was known to wear a small glass medicine bottle on his finger to produce this effect, but it was a very common technique among guitarists. The slides can be made from glass, metal, clay, and other materials (I have seen guitarists use a plastic lighter as a slide in a pinch).